# Why do I have this start session?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have this problem. I install Ubuntu mate in my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but don't like it, so i remove it from Ubuntu.

The problem is that I have this start up panel and I want the default Ubuntu unity..

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In terminal type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select lightdm as default.

Comment: @G_P Answers should be posted as answers. :P In that way you can get proper recognition and upvotes.

Comment: It is too simple to post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe when you install mate it replaced lightdm.

You should install lightdm again.

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default login manager by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

More information is available on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM).